# str has no object add in django

Tags: python, django

Getting this error message when running manage.py

> AttributeError at /accounts/signup/teacher/ 'str' object has no
>   attribute 'add'

This is the code I have written->
forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phonenumber = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_teacher = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(user=user)
        mentor.email.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('email'))
        mentor.firstname.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('firstname'))
        mentor.lastname.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('lastname'))
        mentor.phonenumber.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('phonenumber'))
        mentor.linkedin.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('linkedin'))
        return user
```

models.py

```
#mentor model
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField(null=True,unique=True)
```

and views

```
class TeacherSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = TeacherSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'teacher'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
```

I get this error message when I try and login as a mentor/teacher. Which should then redirect me to  app-instructor-dashboard

Comment: `mentor.email` is just a string, hence `mentor.email.add(..)` makes no sense. The same by the way for all the other `.add(..)`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks and i'm guessing to retrieve the firstname the user filled in I would just write {{mentor.firstname}} in my html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view does not make much sense. An `EmailField` and a `UrlField` are not much more than `CharField`s with some extra validation. These are *not* collections (lists, etc.) of emails.

You thus should assign the values like:

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phonenumber = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super().save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
            firstname=self.cleaned_data['firstname'],
            lastname=self.cleaned_data['lastname'],
            phonenumber=self.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user
```

Note that it will be necessary to *first* save the `user` object. A `User` object that is *not* created at the database side, can not be used to create a `Mentor` object, since then it has no primary key to work with.

Comment: Thanks, will accept, assuming I can for example show a mentor object in an html file using {{mentor.firstname}}?

Comment: @Emm yes,  you can.